# Hide footer when Keyboard Appears- IONIC2

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic2

I want to hide footer in Ionic2 when Keyboard Appears, i searched all the forum but didn't find the correct Solution.

Here is my Footer -

```
<ion-footer>
  <div class="footer1" >
      <p>You don't have account? <span [navPush]="pushPage"> Register here</span></p>
  </div>
</ion-footer>
```

Answer (score 5):

@Und3rTow's answer is quite right, thank you. But a boolean is not really needed:

```
keyboardCheck() {
 return !this.keyboard.isOpen();
}
```

HTML:

```
<ion-footer *ngIf="keyboardCheck()">
 ...
</ion-footer>
```

You can even avoid that function too:

```
<ion-footer *ngIf="!keyboard.isOpen()">
 ...
</ion-footer>
```

Answer (score 4):

You should be able to use the ionic [Keyboard API](http://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/api/platform/Keyboard/#isOpen) for this, more specifically, the `isOpen()` method - something along these lines should work:

```
export class MyClass {

  showFooter: boolean = true;

  constructor(public keyboard: Keyboard) {

  }

  keyboardCheck() {
    if (this.keyboard.isOpen()) {
        // You logic goes here
        this.showFooter = false;
    }
  }
}
```

and in your HTML you can use `ngIf`:

```
<ion-footer *ngIf="showFooter">
  <div class="footer1" >
      <p>You don't have account? <span [navPush]="pushPage"> Register here</span></p>
  </div>
</ion-footer>
```

---

Thanks to @sebaferreras for pointing out that you may need to call [**`resize()`**](http://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/api/components/content/Content/#resize) in order to tell the content to recalculate its dimensions when dynamically adding headers/footers.

Comment: +1 (I was going to answer the same lol). Please notice that when adding/removing the header/footer, you may need to call the `resize()` method from the instance of the content because otherwise the footer will be hidden but the space won't be used for the _content_ ([docs](http://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/api/components/content/Content/#resize)).

Comment: @sebaferreras thanks! Added it to the post. Feel free to add anything further

Comment: Seems perfect to me :)

Comment: Not Working, Nothing is Happening , Sharing my Code,Please have a look-
JS- https://jpst.it/VoQx
HTML- https://jpst.it/VoQO

Please help and Guide me to the Right Door @sebaferreras

Answer (score 2):

I had similar issues.

Now am not very certain which of the keyboard plugins I used but you can try this one: https://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/native/keyboard/

Ensure you first install the plugin, then in your app.scss file, add these lines:

```
 body.keyboard-is-open .scroll-content {
  margin-bottom: 0 !important;
}

body.keyboard-is-open .fixed-content {
  margin-bottom: 0 !important;
}

body.keyboard-is-open .applyFooter{
        display: none;
        bottom: 0;
}
```

Note: I had a class in the footer as class="applyFooter"

```
<ion-footer class="applyFooter">
</ion-footer>
```

Comment: When I try these instructions now, it seems the "keyboard-is-open" class is not added automatically by the plugin.

Answer (score -1):

This is how I solved it for all screens, based on the answer by @Chizitere

1. Install: https://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/native/keyboard/
2. app.component.ts

   ```
   this.platform.ready().then(() => {
     //...

     this.keyboard.onKeyboardShow().subscribe(() => {
       document.body.classList.add('keyboard-is-open');
     });
     this.keyboard.onKeyboardHide().subscribe(() => {
       document.body.classList.remove('keyboard-is-open');
     });
   });
   ```
3. app.scss

   ```
   body.keyboard-is-open ion-footer {
     display: none;
   }
   ```

Comment: My app compiles to a white screen when I use this

Comment: Maybe you did not install the module correctly, check the console logs for any errors.